# Get phone number entered in the redmine custom field and pass parameter to ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twilio, redmine

I want to know how to get value of the phone number entered in the redmine custom field.I want to pass that fetched value to the twilio ruby code so as to send the message to that phone number which is being fetched..Please tel me how to do this..

Code is mentioned below

```
 require 'twilio-ruby'
# To find these visit https://www.twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "yyyy"
auth_token = "xxxx"
begin
  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
  @client.account.messages.create({
                                      :from => 'twilio-ph-no',
                                      :to => '+phone-no-to which msg is sent',
                                      :body => "#{id}";
                                  })
rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError => e
  puts e.message
end
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have any code to share that we can help with?

Comment: Yes I have an twilio code which sends the message..Below code is mentioned.

Comment: require 'twilio-ruby'
# To find these visit https://www.twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "yyyy"
auth_token = "xxxx"
begin
  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
  @client.account.messages.create({
                                      :from => 'twilio-ph-no',
                                      :to => '+phone-no-to which msg is sent',
                                      :body => "#{id}";
                                  })
rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError => e
  puts e.message
end
Want to send ticket-id to that phone-no i type in redmine custom field

Comment: Do you have anything that shows how you've customised Redmine so far?

Comment: sorry...I dint get you..Tell me exactly what is required now?Cant we pass the custom field id to it?

Comment: I don't know how you've customised Redmine, so still can't help. That is certainly code that will work with Twilio, do you know where to put it to make it work in Redmine? Is there anything else that you've already done in code that you can share that would help understand your problem?

Comment: yes I have pasted this code in redmine custom workflow plugin..Its working fine.But I want to send sms to that number which i type manually in redmine custom field

Answer (score 1):

You need first to get the Id of your custom field. You can get it in the URL when you edit your custom field parameters. The URL is like `custom_fields/#ID/edit`

Then your custom field is:

`custom_field = CustomField.find(#ID)`

You can also search by custom field name `CustomField.find_by(name:"UNIQUE_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME")`

Now, to get its value for a specific issue, if you have the `issue_id`, you can do:

```
custom_field_value = CustomValue.find_by(custom_field_id: custom_field_id, customized_type: "Issue", customized_id: issue_id).value
```

I assume each Id belongs to an existing object

Edit: I didn't see you were using the custom workflow plugin. Since you have only direct access to the `@issue` object, you cannot create a CustomValue object and access its properties. You have to go through the `@issue` object:

```
@custom_field_value = @issue.custom_values.where(custom_field_id: id_of_custom_field).pluck(:value)
```

You will get an array of values because some custom fields allow to select more than one item.

Comment: I am writing this code in redmine custom workflow plugin and I get this error:Workflow script executable before saving the issue contains error: undefined local variable or method `custom_field_values_1' for #<Issue:0x007f893b5b97c8>.

Comment: I've edited my answer according to the usage of the custom workflow plugin